# App not starting at startup on all devices

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm developing a Cordova app which i would like to run when the device (re)boots. Now I implemented some native Android code to make this work on Android 5.0.2 (Galaxy Tab S2) and this works fine. But I'm running in some trouble when running the app on a device running 4.4.4 and 4.2.2 (Minix Z64 and Minix X5).

The activity I got for the startup:

```
public class StartupActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And some information in my Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="package.StartupActivity" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So the issue is that the app works fine on my Galaxy Tab S2 since it's starting at boot. But on the other two devices running different versions of Android are not responding to this request.

I'm not that familiar with Android development but since this is working on a newer version of Android I'm thinking this is a compatability issue, if so, is there a workaround for this? Preferably without rooting the device.

Comment: Try to remove `<category ... />` from intent filter. And ensure that app is installed to internal storage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunatly this has no effect on the behaviour on the Minix'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem by declaring the package name of the app in front of `MainActivity.class` and calling the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MY_PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity.class);
    serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(serviceIntent);
}
```